# Excel Generation in ASP.NEt 2.0

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am trying to generate an excel file from my database it working locally but when I try to run it on IIS its giving me this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005.

Here is the code that I am using

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = null;
try
{
  List<Information> InfoList = InfoManager.GetAllInfo);
  .......

 }
```

It is always giving me an error on

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass 
ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

Comment: Really don't do that. There's a MS KB that says you shouldn't use Office components like that on a server (i.e. without an interactive session). Lots of alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed

Comment: FYI 0x80070005 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install AccessDataBaseEngine.exe in your server hosting your application. This will work for both .xls ans xslx.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734

Regards,

Sayed