# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} on azure

Tags: azure

I uploaded an application on Azure. this application allows users to upload an excel file to the underlying database.

the upload excel part of the application uses Microsoft interoperability  and the excel COM component for the code.

however, when uploading the excel file i get the error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Please what can i do to resolve this when hosting the application on Windows Azure

Answer (score 0):

This is because Excel is not installed on your Web Role/Worker Role/Web Site/Virtual Machine. The only way to make your code work is by installing Excel on your Web Role/Worker Role/Virtual Machine but this is something you shouldn't do ([read the KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)).

Consider using OpenXML to work with Excel files: http://nuget.org/packages?q=openxml

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if any of the solutions mentioned here - [Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed) work?

Most probably you need to create this folder - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop and things should work fine.