# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with execution 80080005 Server execution failed

Tags: c#, web-services, com

When I run my web service on the virtual server generated by visual studio my ws works perfectively but, when I run on IISv6 I got this

```
<string xmlns="http://www.devworms.com/">
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {7F12571F-1A8A-11D3-9225-00105ACA290D} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {7F12571F-1A8A-11D3-9225-00105ACA290D} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
</string>
```

what can i do?
I am not using office apis
I am using a dll of Aloha (is a POS)
I think is an iis issue but i don't know
any help???
my code is very simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed)

Comment: Sorry its just windows/microsoft.net......

Answer (score 0):

Try to Register your database working at like this directory i dont know if, mysql,sql,postgres:

in this path:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
```

check this element >system.data> inside of it.

look like this: