# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 800703fa

Tags: .net, com, sqlreportingservice

This error occurs only at specific times and once iis reset is done,it comes back to normal

***I want to know about root cause of this issue.***

This is ocuruing in one of the server which uses sqlreporting services to fetch the data from the db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/456d110b-0180-4929-8d9f-46490cd21c9c/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-fails-after-period-of-inactivity-sharepoint-2010-integrated?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: But the above has occured in sharepoint. How does this relate to the context

Comment: The error code is diiferent for the above metioned so link

Comment: Also my error code is  2147023878

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this?

**Cause:**

The event warning explains that when the profile was being unloaded, the w3wp.exe process had a registry key handle to the profile hive for the user.

As per the kb947238 article, event 1530 occurs because Windows automatically closes any registry handle to a user profile that is left open by an application. This causes the error 800703fa.

The event warning explains that when the profile was being unloaded, the w3wp.exe process had a registry key handle to the profile hive for the user.

As per the kb947238 article, event 1530 occurs because Windows automatically closes any registry handle to a user profile that is left open by an application. This causes the error 800703fa.

**Resolution:**

Go to IIS Manager, select the Application Pool for your web application and click Advanced settings, change the value for “Load User Profile” to “true”

Setting this values makes the IIS loads the user profile for the application pool identity.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/03/01/com-intermittent-error-800703fa-illegal-operation-attempted-on-a-registry-key/

Answer (score 0):

It means:

You have a problem with your dll using:

```
1.) Check dll version compatibility.
2.) if registered(windows/System32).
3.)  microsoft visual c++ redistibutable.
   sometimes this is the one problem that couldn't be explain.
4.) check framework compatibility also if your using IIS.
```