# Jenkins error due to switch Excel 2010 to Excel 2016

Tags: excel, powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which calls a (windows) power shell script. Within that script I call excel by using:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true 
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($myTool)
```

But after upgrading to Excel 2016 (from Excel 2010) this doesn't work anymore. Error message:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002450
0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
At myScript.ps1:99 char:20
+ $excel = new-object <<<< -comobject excel.application
 + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMExcept 
 ion
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman 
 ds.NewObjectCommand
```

I tested myScript and it still works within Windows Powershell ISE, but not when using Jenkins.

I'm running Jenkins on my laptop and use in services->Log On as "this account".

Any idea what could be the issue between Excel 2016 and 2010?

Comment: Check out [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed). Same error, so I assume same solution (it was for me, but not flagging as duplicate in case this is different issue)

Comment: Thnx @gms0ulman . Currently IT-dep. is checking your provided solutions.
Furthermore I tested to change the Jenkins --> Services set to Log on as: "Local System account". 
This brings me some steps further, but more unknown errors pop up, so 
I guess it has to do with the fact that Jenkins and Excel should be the same in Log On settings.
Does anyone know how I should code or set that when Excel is called by Jenkins via the powershell script to also Log on as: "This Account".

In Excel 2010 this was not a problem. I guess between Excel 2010 and Excel 2016 something changed regarding this?