# workbook.SaveAs(Filepath) Not working in Staging env

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to delete empty rows and columns from excel when reading that Excel sheet.
In my local environment working fine.In staging environment not working workbook.SaveAs() functionality.I have placed some log's to read that log for trail and error method , After workbook.SaveAs() line the next log not reading.let me know what is the solution for this.[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lce51.png)

Getting Following error :
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ImportPartNumbersFromexcel()
        {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string UserID = Convert.ToString(Session["userID"]);
        ds = dbOperations.GetPartNumbers(UserID);
        Logger.TestWriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", "GetPartNumbers", null);
        DataTable partnums = ds.Tables[0];
        //  Get all files from Request object  
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
        HttpPostedFileBase file = null;
        string extension = string.Empty;
        string fname = "";
        string NewPath = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
        file = files[i];
        // Checking for Internet Explorer  
        if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
        {
        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
        }
        else
        {
        fname = file.FileName;
        }
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fname);
        extension = fi.Extension;
        fname = UserID + "_" + fname + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + extension;
        // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
        fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/EOrderImports/"), fname);
        file.SaveAs(fname);
        }
        Logger.TestWriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", fname, null);
        string connString = "";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;


        object[,] allValues = (object[,])usedRange.Cells.Value;
        int totalRows = usedRange.Rows.Count;
        if (totalRows == 1)
        {
            return Json("InvalidTemplate", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        #region Delete Empty Rows and Cols from Template
        DeleteEmptyRowsCols(worksheet);
        #endregion

        Logger.TestWriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", "DeleteEmptyRowsCols", null);
        string filename = file.FileName;
        FileInfo fii = new FileInfo(filename);
        fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fii.Name);
        Logger.TestWriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", fname, null);
        string fname1 = string.Empty;

        fname = fname + "_Removed" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + extension;

        // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
        fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/EOrderImports/"), fname);

        Logger.TestWriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", fname1, null);
        //workbook.SaveAs(fname1);
        try
        {
         workbook.SaveAs(fname, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Logger.WriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", ex, null);
        }


        Logger.TestWriteLog("Public", "ImportPartNumbersFromexcel", "SaveAS", null);
        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (in text, not an image) and share the specific details of the code that is failing and what the exception is.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.I have update with code can you check once please

Comment: Please share the specific details of the code that is failing and what the exception is.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception,in the above code after workbook.SaveAs() function log not reading. so i treated as problem in workbook.SaveAs() function. Before this function have some log's and after this also have some log. finally after this function log not reading

Comment: Refactor your code and atleast surround the SaveAs with try catch and add the log in the catch.

most likely you will see permission issues or file path issues

Comment: Likely the user account that IIS is running under does not have write access to `EOrderImports`.

Comment: I have checked all ..all permission given including folder access also but i have one doubt that is .. to delete Excel empty cols,Rows I'm using *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel* ..for this server need any drivers ... ?

Comment: Im getting this error *Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).*

Comment: Looks like you have a dcom issue refer to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed)

I just pasted the content of the fix here.

In DCOMCNFG, right click on the My Computer and select properties.

Choose the COM Securities tab.

In Access Permissions, click Edit Defaults and add Network Service to
   it and give it Allow local access permission. Do the same for <
   Machine_name >\Users.

In Launch and Activation Permissions, click Edit Defaults and add
   Network Service to it and give it Local launch and Local Activation
   permission. Do the same for < Machine_name >\Users.