# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 8000401a

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Facing  issue in below code

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    var excel = new Application();  // this is throwing error
```

Error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the
>   configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.

I am trying to read excel present in `SharePoint`.

How to resolve above issue

Comment: Automating Office like that from ASP.Net is not recommended or supported & can cause all kinds of issues even if you eventually get it into a state where it appears to work.  Consider OleDb/EPPlus as alternatives.

Comment: Make sure the Interop Library you are using is the same version of Excel.  Each version of Excel has a different Interop Library.

Comment: And make sure that Office is installed on the server. As @Alex K mentioned, this is a really bad idea. Microsoft has said don't due this since the 90's in classic ASP days. The threading models are completely wrong and you can easily de-stabilize a server. If you need to read a file, use a component designed for it. For Excel 2010 and above, look at the OpenXML SDK from Microsoft.

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer work to me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974615/12920154